# CheckBox SelectedStateCallback is not working

Tags: java, javafx

My `Movie` entity has a `BooleanProperty` (named as *downloadProperty*) which i wan't to be editable through the `tableview` with a `checkbox`.

With the code bellow, my table column cells are creating correctly. Although when i debug my movie objects after checking the CheckBoxes, `downloadProperty` is still null. What am doing wrong here?

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Movie, BooleanProperty> checkBoxTableColumn;

private void setupCheckBoxColumn() {
    checkBoxTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue().downloadProperty()));
    checkBoxTableColumn.setCellFactory(p -> {
        final CheckBoxTableCell<Movie, BooleanProperty> ctCell = new CheckBoxTableCell<>();
        ctCell.setSelectedStateCallback(index -> moviesTableView.getItems().get(index).downloadProperty());
        return ctCell;
    });
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're wrapping a property in another property for some reason. Use a `TableColumn<Movie, Boolean>` and have the cell value factory simply return `downloadProperty()` without wrapping it in a `SimpleObjectProperty`. Then the default behavior should do what you need, without setting the selected state callback at all. You might need to post your `Movie` class if that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Thanks for once more James. That worked, although i had to use the state callback otherwise the boolean property values would not set.